# Adding multiple sticky divs in jquery sticky plugin

Tags: jquery

Iam using http://stickyjs.com/ plubin for creating sticky divs.In my requirment i have multiple dynamic divs that shoud be sticky while scrolling.I am using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".stickyDiv").each(function(){
        var height =$(".ui-header").height();
        $(this).sticky({ topSpacing: height });
      });
    });
```

this is working fine for me.But when i scroll the page the second sticky div is moving on top of first div.I want to push the first div when second is coming instead of moving on top of first.

Is their any othe plugin that can use multiple sticky divs

Comment: Amm, Maybe adding the `previous .stickyDiv`'s height to the `topSpacing` property? `var height =$(".ui-header").height() + $(".stickyDiv").prev().height()` ?

Comment: While page loading am running the script.so it is taking as null ($(".stickyDiv").prev().height())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead jquery sticky plugin use jquery fixer plugin

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fixed-Position-Elements-Plugin-for-jQuery-Fixer/
```